# Why there's no tag of quantum chaos in physics.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

Why there's no tag of quantum chaos in physics.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 4):

For a composite topic like [quantum chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chaos) it is recommended to use a [tag combination](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chaos-theory+quantum-mechanics): [quantum-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) and [chaos-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chaos-theory).

Tip: To find questions about, say 'quantum chaos', it is often more reliable to search directly on keywords [is:q quantum chaos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+quantum+chaos) rather than tags (as tags are not always applied).

Comment: Why not add another tag?

Comment: To avoid fragmentation.